# Powershell to search in AD by the Employee Name cell up until , (comma)

Tags: excel, powershell, search, cell

I am wondering if PowerShell can go into an excel document, search in a certain worksheet, on a specific column, in a specific cell and in that cell , to select the text only BEFORE, (comma) separator.
In this case the text before ,(comma) separator , is the last name of the user.
Finally I want PowerShell to search for the user by the last name only, for more then 1000 entries.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DJHt.png

Comment: Can definitely be done. Highly recommend you install the Excel Module for PS from GitHub. Once you do, and give it a shot with your code, we will help troubleshoot what you're having issues with (where youre stuck at).

Comment: Sure, Powershell can do that. I'd use the ImportExcel module from Powershell Gallery to get the data from the spreadsheet, split the name on the comma and trim any whitespace, and then use `Get-ADUser -Filter "Surname -eq $LastName"` to fetch the result. You don't need the `-ResultSetSize` parameter since by default the cmdlet will return all results.

Comment: :)))))) yeah that split .... and trim is killing me.

Comment: easy: `($cellText -split ',')[0].Trim()`

Comment: Import-excel gives bad results when trying to go through raw with [-StartRow <Int32>] [-EndRow <Int32>] . It gives me start row 3 and a result from end row 4 . Absolutely bad. Tried it 10 times. 
To cycle through each raw I went: 
1..458 | ForEach-Object { 
$a = $ws.Cells.Item($_,1).Value2
$b = $ws.Cells.Item($_,2).Value2
#where $_ is the number of the raw. It cycles through them better than Import-Excel.
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq $a " | Set-ADUser -title $b -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop | Out-File test100.txt -Append

Answer (score 0):

There aren't many details as to how you want to approach your script, or what properties you want to query from Active Directory but you can start with something like this:

```
# If ImportExcel is not installed:
Install-Module ImportExcel -Scope CurrentUser

$xlsx=Import-Excel 'path/to/excel.xlsx' -WorksheetName 'SheetNameHERE'

if('Employee Name' -notin $xlsx[0].PSObject.Properties.Name)
{
    Write-Warning "Expectected Column Name 'Employee Name' not found."
    break
}

$result=[System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach($usr in $xlsx)
{
    if($usr.'Employee Name'.Contains(','))
    {
        $filter="Surname -eq '{0}'" -f $usr.'Employee Name'.Split(',')[0]
        $adUsr=Get-ADUser -Filter $filter
        
        $result.Add(
            [pscustomobject]@{
                'Employee#'=$usr.'Employee#'
                # Remaining properties you need to query of $adUsr here
        })
    }
}
```